# Laravel node_modules folder < save own/modified modules

Tags: node.js, laravel, node-modules

I am running a laravel project, version 7 right now. I've installed "npm install xxx --save" some modules from git and other datasources - and modified them because I needed them in the project at different locations with small modifications.
E.g. I installed vue-material-year-calendar and copied the year-calendar folder in the node_modules folder into year-calendar12 and modified the vue.files in year-calendar12 folder.
So far so good - npm run watch/dev works and I can use the modified modules as expected.
Today I installed another package which I needed and Laravel mix removed my modified folders from modules.
So I am missing some best practices to do that what I want to achieve :)
How can I tell node that I might leave the "copied and modified" packages there, when I install another package?

Regards
Stev

Comment: The idea is to not edit vendor files but override them later down the line if needs be. If it's not possible to override them for whatever reason, then I would suggest either adding files to your project (i.e. the resources directory), creating your own branch of the package and including that instead of the main package or (where possible/applicable) create a pull request for the main package.

Comment: hey Rwd, thanks for your answer. - so I move the for example year-calendar12 folder in to the resources/js directory and thats it ? Honestly I have no knowledge about git and pull requests and so on < and atm really no time to learn it << I know my fault. Can u if u have a little bit time tell me what u mean with create a pull request for the main package? Thank you very much!

Comment: A pull request is essentially a way for you to ask the developers of a package to include the changes you made in to the main package i.e. a bug fix or a new feature. This would usually be done by creating a fork of the main repo, making/committing your changes and then creating a pull request with those changes. If the changes are only really applicable to your project and wouldn't really help anyone else then chances are the pull request will be rejected. https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/352/what-exactly-is-a-pull-request

Comment: Thank you very much .. for bringing me nearer to git and thank you fro your time!